# In python multiple inheritance, is it possible for one parent to access another parent without knowing what that parent is?

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

In my code, I have the inheritance relation `B -> C -> D`, and there is a particular function `f` of interest here

```
class C(B):
    def f(self):
        if <some condition>:
            B.f(self)
        else:
            <do other stuff>
```

And the issue is that there are multiple possibilities of `B` in reality, but the logic of `C` is the same. A straightforward way is then to use linear inheritance multiple times, i.e.,

```
B1 -> C1 -> D1
B2 -> C2 -> D2
B3 -> C3 -> D3
```

However, it is wasteful. Then I am thinking of using multiple inheritance

```
D1(C, B1)
D2(C, B2)
D3(C, B3)
```

Then the problem is how does `C.f()` access `B1.f()` (same for `B2`, `B3`) since it only knows the existence of `B1` via `D1`?

Is this a bad idea to use multiple inheritance in this case? Or is there a better way than both the straightforward linear inheritance with multiple `C`s and multiple inheritance (if it works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a classic problem on multiple-inheritance that ultimately led some languages to opt-out from multiple-inheritance at all.

Python however, got away just by putting in place a cleverly crafted "method resolution order" (mro) algorithm, and later, with the advent of the `super` built-in call. The algorithm and its history are detailed in https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

But, long history short, it just works as expected "by heart". For example, by pasting this code on the interactive interpreter:

```
class A: pass
class B(A): 
    def f(self): raise NotImplementedError
class C(B):
    def f(self):
        super().f()
        print("C")
class B1(B): f = lambda s: print("B1")
class B2(B): f = lambda s: print("B2")
class D(C, B1): pass
class D1(C, B2): pass
```

We get these results when tinkering along:

```
In [25]: D().f()
B1
C

In [26]: D1().f()
B2
C

In [27]: D.__mro__
Out[27]: (__main__.D, __main__.C, __main__.B1, __main__.B, __main__.A, object)
```